# insertbefore() in loop only adds the first row, fails on the others

Tags: javascript, dom, loops, xpath, greasemonkey

I am using Greasemonkey and JavaScript to write annotations for a web page. I want to add the same `<td>` to multiple rows, but the code only works for the first row.

Here is what I have:

```
var headings2 = document.evaluate('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/font/center[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2]',document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null );
var thisHeadings2 = headings2.iterateNext(); 
var elmAnnotation2 = document.createElement('td');
  elmAnnotation2.innerHTML = 
    '<font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#000080">' +
    '<b>Response</b>' +
    '</font>';
while(thisHeadings2){
  thisHeadings2.parentNode.insertBefore(elmAnnotation2.cloneNode(true), thisHeadings2);
  thisHeadings2 = headings2.iterateNext();
}
```

Comment: You're adding a `td` inside of a `td`?

Comment: Not inside but outside before a td

Comment: @wonderful93, no, `createElement` generates automatically the tag of the constructor when adding it to the DOM, Crazy Train is right

Comment: @LightStyle,OK,even if I remove the '<td>' in the innerHTML,I still only can add once.

Comment: What logging have you done inside the loop?

Comment: @Train, I'm not very sure I understand your question. I don't think I did anything more than two lines of code in the while loop.

Comment: according to http://help.dottoro.com/ljtfvvpx.php, modifying the document breaks the iteration. use document.querySelectorAll() instead of xpath for collections that won't break upon modification...

Comment: @dandavis,Yes, that's what I need!! Now I am using the  snapshotItem method instead of iterateNext() and I get it. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Don't put the answer in your question!  Make an answer out of the answer you found.

Comment: @Brock Adams, Ok, will do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dandavis. According to this: http://help.dottoro.com/ljtfvvpx.php, modifying the document invalidates the iteration, but does not invalidate the snapshots collection. So now I am using snapshots and I fixed it. Here is the solution:

```
var headings2 = document.evaluate('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/font/center[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td[2]',document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
var elmAnnotation2 = document.createElement('td');
elmAnnotation2.innerHTML = 
    '<font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial" color="#000080">' +
    '<b>Response</b>' +
    '</font>';    
for(var i = 0; i < headings2.snapshotLength; i++){
    headings2.snapshotItem(i).parentNode.insertBefore(elmAnnotation2.cloneNode(true), headings2.snapshotItem(i));
}
```